# Bayesian update vs optimization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, optimization, bayes-theorem

Say I have a multivariate normal vector

$r$~$N(\mu , \Sigma ) => Pr$~$N(P\mu , P'\Sigma P )$

and I observe that

$  Pr = Q$

Now I can use Bayes rule to calculate the updated mean of $r$ using the formula mentioned [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html)

$E(r/ (Pr =Q)) = \mu + \Sigma P'[ P \Sigma^{-1}P']^{-1
}[Q - P\mu]$......................................(i)

This is the same expression as would be derived if you minimized

$(r - \mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(r-\mu)$ subject to $Pr = Q $.............(ii)

My question is- why does the constrained minimization (ii) give the same result as the bayesian updating case (i)?  Is there a conceptual link?